# How to add SVG component as full App background in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React native trying to add an SVG component in App.js file so my complete app have same background. I also try to use Image background which is also not working. Please help me in this

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SafeAreaView style={style.safeContainer}>
        <StatusBar
          backgroundColor={DARK_COLORS.primaryDark}
          barStyle="light-content"
        />
        <AppBackground>
          {/* <ImageBackground
          source={require('./assets/svg/AppBackground.svg')}
          resizeMode={'cover'}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}> */}
          <RouteHome />
          {/* </ImageBackground> */}
        </AppBackground>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Svg from "svg_file_path"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SafeAreaView style={style.safeContainer}>
        <StatusBar
          backgroundColor={DARK_COLORS.primaryDark}
          barStyle="light-content"
        />
        <AppBackground>
        
          <RouteHome />
          <Svg/> <--here is your svg 
        </AppBackground>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Check this for more info : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg